# My last accepted answers = 15 points each

Tags: support, reputation, accepted-answer

I gained two accepted answer today. Each one has raised my reputation with 15 points instead of 25 as before. What is the reason of this change? :

- I had 990 points ; after 1000 points, the raising is with 15 and no more with 25?
- Is it because each accepted answer gains 15 points when one gains several accepted answer in one day ?
- Is it one of the recent changes that occured in the stackoverflow.com site?

I searched in the "Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange" thread but I didn't see any mention of that.

Comment: Accepted answers always get 15.  If you get it along with an upvote, then you get 25 - 15 for accept, 10 for up vote.  In the latter cases, you probably got no upvotes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Accepting an answer has always been 15 reputation points. Upvoting gives you 10 points. Generally what happens is, that the OP upvotes and accepts the answer and hence you feel you got 25 points. But it is not. It is 10 for upvoting + 15 for accepting.

After seeing your recent reputation list, it seems that both answers which were accepted today has 0 upvotes. Hence you have got +15 twice which is correct. Snapshot given below -

[image]

Your answer is below -

[image]

Comment: Thank you. If I had examined more accurately the subject, I would have understood alone. Sometimes I believe or do something, and after that, I realize I was out of my brain.

Comment: @eyquem - Guess you are lucky to get 25 all the way till you hit 1000 rep.... :)  Just kidding...

Answer (score 3):

According to the FAQ and accecpted answer is only worth 15 points.  I don't ever recall it being worth 25.